# Does chaining commutative operations improve performance?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I have some OpenCL kernels which are interfacing with python threw the pyopencl library. The kernels are used to speed up commutative operations (like addition or multiplication), where the order of the operating input variables does not matter. A kernel doing addition might look like this:

```c
__kernel void addition(__global const float *a_g,
                       __global const float *b_g, 
                       __global float *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = a_g[gid] + b_g[gid];
}
```

For simplicity, assume all the operating buffers (`a_g`, `b_g`, `res_g`) are of the same size and 1 dimensional. The global work size is set to the size of the buffers before launching the kernel and the result is stored in the `res_g` buffer.

These operations work in a sequential manner, the output from one kernel is used as the input to the next kernel. Given that all these kernels look like the code snippet above, I could simply "chain" adding together 4 inputs by writing the following kernel:

```c
__kernel void addition_chained(__global const float *a_g,
                               __global const float *b_g, 
                               __global const float *c_g,
                               __global const float *d_g,
                               __global float *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = a_g[gid] + b_g[gid] + c_g[gid] + d_g[gid];
}
```

With this, no intermediary result buffers needs to be allocated and there is no overhead in launching new threads.

Is this a common optimization? What are the pros and cons of doing this?

Is there any canonical way to chain kernels in OpenCL? The amount of operations that need chaining might not be known at compile-time.

Comment: As a side note: *I am not sure if chaining is the correct term*

Answer (score 2):

Reducing kernel calls by combining the actions of multiple kernels into one means less memory allocation and less memory transfers from global memory, which significantly reduces execution time.

If the number of additions is constant throughout your program, you can use to your advantage that OpenCL is compiled from a string at runtime. That means: You can at runtime modify the string containing the OpenCL code, and then compile and run it. This way, you can add a variable number of kernel arguments and summation terms via string concatenation.

If however the number of summation terms charges many times within one execution of your program and is unpredictable, the two-argument kernel is the way to go. Otherwise you would have to recompile the OpenCL code many times which has significant overhead.

Comment: Manipulating the string like this feels bit hacky, but I suppose this is exactly what I am trying to do.